# Non-negative integer solutions to $x+2y+3z=104$ and $3y+4z=60$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x+2y+3z=104$

$3y+4z= 60$

I am trying to find the non-negative integer solutions, of which I know there are six, but I do not know how to get them.

Are there any easy methods of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is difficult to know what you want. Are you searching for non-negative integral solutions to the two equations $x+2y+3z=104$ and $3 y + 4 z = 60$ or something else? What is the $6$, the number of solutions?

Comment: There is a third relation, namely $x-y-z=44$.

Comment: @Autolatry How do you know?

Comment: @egreg It is implied by the two equations. Subtract them.

Comment: @user31415 So it's completely irrelevant

Comment: @egreg The comment is unclear. He may have meant to say it as a hint.

Comment: @user31415 it is absolutely a hint - you have three equations in three unkowns now.

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation you get
$$
3y=4(15-z)
$$
which implies that $y$ must be divisible by $4$: $y=4Y$. Thus $3Y=15-z$, from which $z=3(5-Y)$. Therefore $z$ is divisible by $3$: $z=3Z$.

Now we have $12Y+12Z=60$, that gives $Y+Z=5$.

Thus you have six solutions:
$$
Y=0, Z=5\\
Y=1, Z=4\\
Y=2, Z=3\\
Y=3, Z=2\\
Y=4, Z=1\\
Y=5, Z=0
$$
The first equation becomes
$$
x=104-8Y-9Z
$$
and any pair $Y,Z$ above is good.

Comment: What's the matter with downvoting?